# Stuck with linking SQL queries together

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying get the MAX value of my subquery denoted as NUM_of_CUST column and to display it alongside with the artist name in tge main query so it would display like this:

ARTIST_NAME | NUM_of_CUST

```
Select A.Lastname ||''|| A.FirstName as Artist_Name from dhey.ARTIST A 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM(
SELECT COUNT(*) As Num_of_Customer From Dhey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT CAI
GROUP BY ARTISTID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) WHERE ROWNUM = 1) B on A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID;
```

However SQL is throwing me B"."ARTISTID": invalid identifier exception.

Can anyone advise on this?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want `SELECT ArtistID, COUNT(*)` in the inner most query...

Answer (score 2):

I do not really understand what you want to do but i think it is either you want the number of customers per artist

```
Select  A.Lastname ||''|| A.FirstName as Artist_Name 
        COUNT(*) as nb_cust
from dhey.ARTIST A 
LEFT outer JOIN Dhey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT B on A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID
group by A.ArtistID, A.Lastname ||''|| A.FirstName
order by nb_cust desc
```

Or you want the max number of customer overall and link that to your artist... which is a cross product with one line.

```
Select  A.Lastname ||''|| A.FirstName as Artist_Name 
        nb_cust_max
from dhey.ARTIST A 
cross join  (   select max(nb_cust) as nb_cust_max
                from    (   select count(*) as nb_cust 
                            From Dhey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT 
                            group by ARTISTID
                        )
            )
```

Am I close ? or totally wrong?

Otherwise, as suggested by **MatBailie**, you can just add the missing field

```
Select A.Lastname ||''|| A.FirstName as Artist_Name from dhey.ARTIST A 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM(
SELECT ARTISTID, COUNT(*) As Num_of_Customer From Dhey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT CAI
GROUP BY ARTISTID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) WHERE ROWNUM = 1) B on A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID;
```

Comment: Hey Steve, Sorry for not being clear on this, I'm trying to find out Which artist has the most customers interested in him/her, and
how many customers are interested in them? 

The Schema for the two tables are as follows:
CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT(CustomerID, ArtistID)
ARTIST(ArtistID, Firstname, Lastname)

Comment: then 1st query i publised. You can add a `order by` at the end to have the top first.

Comment: I'm trying this:

SELECT A.lastname ||''||A.firstname as Artist_Name
FROM dtoohey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT CAI
LEFT JOIN dtoohey.CUSTOMER C
ON CAI.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
LEFT JOIN dtoohey.ARTIST A
ON CAI.ARTISTID = A.ARTISTID
WHERE A.ARTISTID =
(SELECT ArtistID, COUNT(*) FROM dtoohey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT
group by ArtistID
order by COUNT(*) desc);


I got the main query working but the subquery isn't working, am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: your "where" clause is not good. You are trying to compare an artist id to a couple (artist id, count)

Comment: Okay, I'm kinda stuck here, my subquery was supposed to count the number of instances of artistIDs per artist ID, take the artistID with the max count and then join with the main query to show the artist name followed by the max count.

Sorry for troubling you

Comment: I think you try to complicate everything. Take a step back. What do your data represent? Forget the column name and think about the business meaning, what you want to display.  If you want efficient help, give us the data structure and the business requirement.

Comment: The data structure is CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT(CustomerID, ArtistID) ARTIST(ArtistID, Firstname, Lastname) CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID) and my business requirement is which artist has the most customers interested in him or her, and
how many customers are interested in them?

So far I managed to do this:

SELECT A.lastname ||''||A.firstname as Artist_Name, COUNT(CAI.ARTISTID) AS NumberOfCustomers,
FROM dtoohey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT CAI
LEFT JOIN dtoohey.CUSTOMER C
ON CAI.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
LEFT JOIN dtoohey.ARTIST A
ON CAI.ARTISTID = A.ARTISTID
group by  A.lastname,  A.firstname;

Comment: It is working but I'm not sure how to retrive only the row with the most count

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my answer with this

```
SELECT A.lastname ||''||A.firstname as Artist_Name, COUNT(CAI.ARTISTID) AS NumberOfCustomers
FROM dhey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT CAI
LEFT JOIN dhey.CUSTOMER C
ON CAI.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
LEFT JOIN dhey.ARTIST A
ON CAI.ARTISTID = A.ARTISTID
group by  A.lastname,  A.firstname
having count(*) = (select max(count(ArtistID))
                     from dhey.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT
                    group by ArtistID);
```

Thank you all that helped!